# Spring boot: Cannot serialize Int as Float

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm using a ready Jackson-databind serializer to return an integer field as float:

```
@XmlElement(name = "toPick")
@Column(name = "to_pick")
@JsonSerialize(using = FloatSerializer.class)
private Integer toPick;
```

But I get this message during serialization:

> Could not write content: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use an IntegerSerializer?

```
@XmlElement(name = "toPick")
@Column(name = "to_pick")
@JsonSerialize(using = IntegerSerializer.class)
private Integer toPick;
```

Comment: It will take integer one by default. I need a different serializer

Comment: _"I need a different serializer"_ WHY?

Comment: Its the type you're serializing from.. if you look into the serializer:  serialize(String topic, Integer data) .. it needs an Integer to work.. not a float